# How to show hide specific div in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

> HTML:-

```
'<td>' + item.Message + ' <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="' + item.LogID + '" onclick="Clicked(this);" value="View More"  /> <p> ' + item.FormattedMessage + ' </p></td></tr>'
```

this is button in table

> Jquery:-

```
 function Clicked(e)
        {
            var SelectedID = e.id;
            $("p").toggle();
        };
```

In this  When i click on button i want to show selected id column only and hide rest columns.
But when i click on button it shows all column or hides all column

Comment: `var SelectedID = e.id;
        $("#" + SelectedID).next().toggle();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to balachandar answer. if you want to hide `p` tag initially then use `display:none` for `p` tag

```js
function Clicked(e)
    {
        var SelectedID = e.id;
        
        $("#"+SelectedID).next("p").toggle(function(){
        
          var btn_text =  $("#"+SelectedID).val();
  
          if(btn_text == "View More"){
    
             $("#"+SelectedID).val("Hide");
          }else{
           $("#"+SelectedID).val("View More")
          }
        
        
        });
       
     
    
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="myID" onclick="Clicked(this)" value="View More"  /> <p style="display:none"> Some Text you want to in future </p>
```

Comment: please change the code like below
$("#"+SelectedID).next("p").toggle();
I was missed .(dot) before toggle() method.

Comment: Thanks @balachandar

Comment: what is not working? still you can see p tag? did you add style attribute?

Comment: yes added display property but when i click on button it doent show p

Comment: is your p tag hidden initially?

Comment: i updated my answer with example. please take a look

Comment: var SelectedID = e.id;
            var toggle_switch = $(this);
            $("#" + SelectedID).next("p").toggle(function () {
                if (toggle_switch.css('display') == 'none') {
                    toggle_switch.html('View more');
                } else {
                    toggle_switch.html('Hide');
                }
            });

Comment: can u tell me how to change button value on toggle??

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code

```
 function Clicked(e)
    {
        var SelectedID = e.id;
        $("#"+SelectedID).next("p").toggle();
    };
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It worked!!!! but i it shows "P" content. i want to hide P content.when i click on button then it should show  P content

Comment: @RookieCoder you want hide and show p content while click the button right?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element by its id and find the `p` element inside:

```
 function Clicked(e)
    {
        var SelectedID = e.id;
        $("#" + SelectedID).find("p").toggle();
    };
```

Or just use `this`:

```
 function Clicked(e)
    {
        $(this).find("p").toggle();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Clicked(e)
    {
        var SelectedID = e.id;
        $("#" + SelectedID).toggle();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
function Clicked(d)
{
    var SelectedID = d.id;
    $("#" + SelectedID).toggle();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This function picks all `p` inside `td` of your table and hides all of them, then it shows only the one with the same ID as the button.

```
function Clicked(e) {
    var SelectedID = e.id;
    $("td p").hide();
    $("#" + SelectedID).show();
};
```